# Bounced emails are not getting redirected to Email service address

Tags: apex-email-service

i have a user **SystemCogauser(admin user)** which has Email Service address in it's email Id field.

In some perticular functionality, The user **SystemCogauser** triggers emails to the end users. if any email get bounced, the bounced email should be redirected to the 
Email Service address as we have configured it in SystemCogauser's email id.
Then, The email handler class should get triggered and create a case in salesforce as per the requirement.

But the bouced email itself not getting redirected to Email Service address.

am i missing anything in the configuration? Please share if you have any idea?

**Note1:** In Deliverability , "Return bounced emails to sender " has been enabled under Bounce Management.

**Note2:** For the users who are having the correct email id, its showing email service address in FROM address.
Hence, the Bounced emails also should be redirected to Email service address only. But it is not at all happeining.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is happening in a sandbox?  You might have "Email Deliverability" set to "No Access".  Is that it?  I think i also recall there being a setting on Email Services similar to Allow Email From.  Check that too.

Comment: yeah i'm trying this in sandbox and the Email Deliverability has set to "All Email" only. Still i'm facing this issue.

Comment: The Email Service itself might be inactive and/or might not accepting email from the sender. Check its settings carefully.